# How do I get the value of a child div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day,
I would like to ask how I can get the value from price. Neither of them has a unique id so it makes things hard for a noob like me. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
<div class="modal">
    <span class="name">$</span>
    <span class="price">0.04</span>
    <hr style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffc82d , #ffff73);">
    <div class="weapon" style="background-image: url('assets/img/free_case_item.png');"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript is required.

Comment: Why do you want to get the value of it, can you be more specific ? You should actually give it a ID because if class "price" is used in more occasions your JS can get trouble to get its value but if it is only for that price it's easy and not that hard, but still try to use Ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with pure JavaScript using DOM manipulation.

Assuming you only have one element with the `price` class: `document.getElementsByClassName("price").item(0).innerText`.

Ideally you would give it an ID (e.g. price): `document.getElementById("price").innerText`

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
var price = document.querySelector("div.modal span.price").innerText
```

This matches the first `<span class="price">` inside `<div class="modal">`.